# Output Laravel collection in groups of two

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm struggling to split the table into two columns in Laravel blade. For example if I have 17 rows, I want to display 9 of them in first column, and the rest in the second. This is my code:

```
@foreach($idAndProducts as $id)
<tr>
<td width="15px">
<input type="checkbox" id="products{{$id->product_id}}" name="products[]" value="{{$id->product_id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="campaignID[]" value="{{$id->id}}"></td>
<td width="480px"><label for="products{{$id->product_id}}">{{$id->products}}</label></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Is there a way to do this within a Blade or using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split them into groups of two. Try this:

```
@foreach ( array_chunk($idAndProducts, 2) as $row )
    <tr>
    @foreach ( $row as $id )
        <td width="15px">
            <input type="checkbox" id="products{{$id->product_id}}" name="products[]" value="{{$id->product_id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="campaignID[]" value="{{$id->id}}">         
        </td>
        <td width="480px">
            <label for="products{{$id->product_id}}">{{$id->products}}</label>
        </td>
    @endforeach
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Please note that if `$idAndProducts` is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) then `array_chunk` will not work. You will need to use the inbuilt method [`chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-chunk) instead. Just update the first line to read

```
@foreach ( $idAndProducts->chunk(2) as $row )
```

Comment: I just updated my answer. I wasn't sure if `$idAndProducts` was a collection or not.

Comment: Sorry. I've just seen your edit and deleted my comment which stated about collection error. Now it works perfectly. Thx!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!